# How to link my Flutter App contacts to android's native contact application?

Tags: android, flutter, contacts, android-contacts

I want to display a linked contact of my flutter app in android's native contact application like facebook, WhatsApp and googles does as shown in the picture below. I am aware of the logic behind it, just can't put the links to the native contact application. Any suggestions would be much appreciated. [image: First Image][image: second-Image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably need the proper platform-specific plugins.  The description for https://pub.dev/packages/contacts_service looks pretty close.

Comment: I have used the plugin you mentioned to fetch the contacts from android and saved it to my app. But I still cant figure out how to  link my own contact to and existing one.